# Duplication of value in the ArrayList while performing Pagination in android

Tags: java, android, pagination

i have a situation where my list inflated with duplicate value if we upload some new post in the backend.

At the first fetch we are setting the limit as 0(start value) to 5(max limit) so that i can get 5 post from the backend that will be displayed in the recyclerview & during scrolling the recyclerview my next fetch limit is 5(next index) to 5(max limit),so that next 5 post gets inflated in the list,upto this is working perfectly , But if some person have posted some new Post in the backend & i tried to scrolls without fetching the latest posts,the recyclerview gets inflated with duplicate entry.

I'm little confused how to tackle this situation either i have to remove the duplicate entries from the list by using LinkedHashSet or i have to give some logic that gives me correct data from the server.

Comment: While fetching data first clear your list and than add new data,this happens because you have already some data in your list and you added new data as well as old data that's why you get the duplicate previous data,so just clear your list before add into the list.

Comment: if we clear the data from the list & again load data say from 0 to 10 then i think it lead to performance issue since i 'm wasting  my internet to load data that is already loaded from server...@AbhishekPatel

Comment: maybe you can fix this by choosing the right strategy in your backend: lazy and eager fetch. Which one do you use now. Lazy?

Comment: maintain a hasmap having unique key. Store each key into hashmap while loading items into recyclerview. Hashmap is faster and checks whether new item is already existed or not. If existed leave it. If not existed add it to recycler view.

Comment: Let me try this @TrickySolutions

Answer (score 1):

Give each of your post a unique `Auto Increment` id. Send that id in request instead of index. So server will always return items before that id while scrolling.

Comment: we could try this...Thanks